# Pass A Session Value To Another Session Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I have an `asp.net webform` page which has 2 radio buttons, these radio buttons store the selected value in `session`, and is displayed on my confirmation page. When the user clicks the submit button an email is sent with all the details (again all details are displayed by `session`).

I have an issue getting the value of the selected radio button in my email. The only option I can see would be to have 2 identical field labels where one would be empty and the other would display the selected value from the session.

I tried adding the below `IF` to my email body but it removes all details from my email.

I was thinking I could use an `IF statement` in my `.cs` file to check that one of the radio buttons is not `null` and then create another `session variable`. I can't figure out how to pass the `session` value which is in the `IF` condition to populate a new `session`.

**HTML For Page With Radio Buttons On**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label ID="PrefContactLabel" class="col-sm-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Preferred method of contact *" style="padding-top: 0px"></asp:Label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline" style="padding-top: 0px">
               <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="PhoneRadioButton" value="Phone" GroupName="prefcontact"/> Phone
          </asp:Label>
               <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline" style="padding-top: 0px">
               <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="EmailRadioButton" value="Email" GroupName="prefcontact"/> Email
          </asp:Label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
          <asp:CustomValidator id="custPrefContact" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please select a preferred method of contact." ClientValidationFunction="PrefContact_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="PrefContact_ServerValidate" />
     </div>
</div>
```

**Code Behind For Page With Radio Buttons On**

```
protected void Step01SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["PhoneRadioButton"] = PhoneRadioButton.Checked ? "Phone" : "";
     Session["EmailRadioButton"] = EmailRadioButton.Checked ? "Email" : "";
}
```

This is a start to the `IF` statement I was adding to the above code

```
if (Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() == "Phone" || Session["EmailRadioButton"].ToString() == "Email")
{
     Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] = Step01HiddenPrefField.Text;
}
```

This is the line of code which breaks my email on my confirmation page

```
Label4.Text + " " + Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() == "Phone" ? Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() : Session["EmailRadioButton"].ToString();
```

I want to populate my "Session["PrefContactRadioButton"]" with the value from the "Session["PhoneRadioButton"]/Session["EmailRadioButton"]".

Comment: The line that "breaks" does not seem to use any of the Session variables form your previous code.

Comment: @Magnus Sorry i have the line commented out and have since changed my session names but i have updated the line that breaks it section

Comment: What exactly is it that breaks? What is the error you get? I still don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't belive after nearly a month of trying sort this out, its just come to me, Just use the same `session` name for both radio buttons, and guess what it worked.

Updated `.cs` code

```
    if (PhoneRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] = PhoneRadioButton.Checked ? "Phone" : "";
    }
    else if (EmailRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] = EmailRadioButton.Checked ? "Email" : "";
    }
```

Then updated my confirmation page to call my new `session` variable

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Step01ContactMethod" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Preferred method of contact:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 form-control-static">                            
            <%=Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And finaly updated my confirmation page email body

```
msg.Body = Step01ContactMethod.Text + " " + Session["PrefContactRadioButton"].ToString();
```

And voila it works.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks dangerous for me:

```
Label4.Text + " " + Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() == "Phone" ? Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() : Session["EmailRadioButton"].ToString();
```

If you use ternary operator in string concatenation, put parenthesis around it.

```
Label4.Text + " " + (Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() == "Phone" ? Session["PhoneRadioButton"].ToString() : Session["EmailRadioButton"].ToString());
```